# import.io crawler does not fill text columns that are filled during training (on the same sites as in the stream)

Tags: regex, xpath, web-scraping, artificial-intelligence, import.io

import.io looks great to speed up web scraping by training the tool on a few pages what to extract from crawled sites. Yet I don't understand what's wrong with my current crawler. I trained it to run through precinct reports from Hungary (for voting records). During training, the first two text fields are recognized correctly, even if I train on the exact same pages that came up in the stream during crawling. Meanwhile, the columns are left blank during crawling in the end. What is going on/wrong? Thanks!

The crawler is at `https://import.io/data/mine/?id=772c725f-6048-4861-9f73-03ae30d8f7cc`

An example page for the first row of the stream is `http://valasztas.hu/dyn/pv14/szavossz/hu/M08/T150/szkjkv_029.html`

The first two lines of the saved stream are:

> ```
> _url,_position,szavazokor,valasztokerulet,valasztok_szama,megjelentek_szama,megjelentek_szama/_source,ervenyes_lapok_szama,ervenyes_lapok_szama/_source,mcp,mcp/_source,haza_nem_elado,haza_nem_elado/_source,sms,sms/_source,fkgp,fkgp/_source,udp,udp/_source,fidesz,fidesz/_source,sem,sem/_source,lmp,lmp/_source,jesz,jesz/_source,ump,ump/_source,munkaspart,munkaspart/_source,szocialdemokratak,szocialdemokratak/_source,kti,kti/_source,egyutt2014,egyutt2014/_source,zoldek,zoldek/_source,osszefogas,osszefogas/_source,kormanyvaltok,kormanyvaltok/_source,jobbik,jobbik/_source,osszes_ervenyes_listas,osszes_ervenyes_listas/_source
> "http://valasztas.hu/dyn/pv14/szavossz/hu/M08/T150/szkjkv_029.html","1","","","825","478","478","478","478","0","0","1","1","2","2","1","1","0","0","221","221","1","1","34","34","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","2","1","1","3","3","0","0","129","129","80","80","475","475"
> ```

Instead, `szavazokor` should say `Sopron 029` from the page and `valasztokerulet` should say `GYŐR–MOSON–SOPRON 04`.

I found no option to look deep into what pattern the crawler is looking for after the training.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at your crawler, and it is indeed strange that it is not functioning as you would expect, given that it matches all the training data provided - I have asked the team to look into it.

There is a potential workaround in that you can specify a manual regex override for columns, which you may have more luck with.

When you create your first column (or, click the "text" link in the column header to edit an existing column) you can check the "Advanced" box, and provide a "Manual Regex override". In here I put `(.+?).számú szavazókör`. For the second column I used `(.+?).számú egyéni választókerületi szavazás`.

Does that resolve your issue?

p.s. if you hadn't already guessed, I work at import.io

Comment: Thanks, I did try the manual overrides over the weekend, they did not help. (And I would also need to them more complicated as for single-precinct villages the text is slightly different: http://valasztas.hu/dyn/pv14/szavossz/hu/M14/T002/szkjkv_001.html)

Comment: Plus there is a third variant, but actually I would need this information for a separate column (a simple 0/1 yes/no, whether this precinct was a special one), see this: http://valasztas.hu/dyn/pv14/szavossz/hu/M01/T018/szkjkv_034.html